# How to get Finger iD (which finger is used for touch id) , or unique touch id on IOS/SWIFT/OBJ-C/CORDOVa

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova, fingerprint

I want to detect which finger is scanned to touch id ?
For example user will scan his 2nd finger, can a plugin or apple's touchid framework returns indices of finger, or unique id of which fingerprint scanned.

I just want to detect which finger is printed in ios/swift/obj-c

Answer (score 5):

No, this information is not available.

The secure enclave processor inside the device that analyses the fingerprint simply returns a yes/no that a valid fingerprint was matched

Answer (score 2):

@Paulw11 is correct, we can not access the data of finger prints.

From Apple excerpts:

Touch ID doesn't store any images of your fingerprint. It stores only a mathematical representation of your fingerprint. It isn't possible for someone to reverse engineer your actual fingerprint image from this mathematical representation. The chip in your device also includes an advanced security architecture called the Secure Enclave which was developed to protect passcode and fingerprint data. Fingerprint data is encrypted and protected with a key available only to the Secure Enclave. Fingerprint data is used only by the Secure Enclave to verify that your fingerprint matches the enrolled fingerprint data. The Secure Enclave is walled off from the rest of the chip and the rest of iOS. Therefore, iOS and other apps never access your fingerprint data, it's never stored on Apple servers, and it's never backed up to iCloud or anywhere else. Only Touch ID uses it, and it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.

Comment: "The best way to store a password is to not store a password"